# Using variables in a large number of places for table names in a stored procedure in Sybase

Tags: t-sql, sybase

I have a procedure that archives records from a source database into a destination database, where the tables in the source database are mirrored in the destination database. Therefore, when I specify a table name, I must also specify the database name in full, as the following:

```
DB_NAME.dbo.TABLE_NAME
```

However, I must also move this stored procedure between environments, where the corresponding databases are named differently.

For example:

Dev:

```
DEV_DB_NAME.dbo.TABLE_NAME
```

QA:

```
QA_DB_NAME.dbo.TABLE_NAME
```

I can obtain these DB names from environment variables using a SHELL script and pass them into the SPROC. However, TSQL does not allow variables for database names.

I have a solution where I basically just turn the entire script into a string and run with `exec` using dynamic SQL.

Is my solution recommended? Are there any other solutions?

Thanks.

Comment: why you cannot just use dbo.TABLE_NAME  instead of DB_Name.dbo.TABLE_NAME ? Are you referencing more than 1 database in stored proc?

Comment: @ClearLogic, Yes I am referencing 2 databases within the same SPROC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use sqsh, which is an isql alternative that allows you to define variables, rather like shell vars, enabling you to install the same DDL to different databases with things like database names replaced correctly.

or roll your own with shell variables and feed isql with different Sql in a shell variable or temporary file.

Or do you have to use an SP in this case?  It doesn't sound like it's taking advantage of one of SPs' primary benefits: optimise once and run many times, saving opimisation time.  In which case use a shell script or perl script to do your tasks, and provide command line parameters/config file/environment vars to say which databases.

Answer (score 0):

How about creating Synonyms? and use Synonyms in the Stored Proc.Then Each Envorinment can define those same Synonyms differently.

I hope Synonyms in Sybase can be defined across database like SQL Server 2008.